# Let $f(x) = \frac{x(x−1)(x−2)\cdots(x−n)}{(x + 1)(x + 2)\cdots(x + n)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

It's my first time asking questions on this community. Could you guys help me?

Let $$f(x) = \frac{x(x−1)(x−2)\cdots(x−n)}{(x + 1)(x + 2)\cdots(x + n)}$$

a) Find $f '(0)$

b) Suppose that the function $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x, y \in\mathbb{R}$.

If $k:=f '(0)$, show that $f '(x)= k f(x)$.

(Consider the cases $f (0) = 0$ and $f(0)$ is not the same as $0$ separately.)

Thank you so much

( I've been attempting to solve the problem (A) by multiplying and dividing the function in order to simplify the function and looking for the "logic" of this problem and yet I still don't know how to solve the problem. Sorry if you guys feel that way! I'll try to solve it again, I'm so sorry :) )

Update: 
For problem A, I've tried and found the answer by using an internet calculator (wolfram alpha) So, here it is:

if n is an odd number, the answer will be=-1

if n is an even number, the answer will be=1.

But I am not too sure about it and therefore, I need strong proof that can prove my answer and I really hope that you guys could help me.

Comment: Questions of the form "here's my problem, solve it for me" are badly taken in this community. [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2974459/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Have you attempted anything so far? If so, could you show it so that we can help you see where you went wrong?

Comment: I've been attempting to solve the problem (A) by multiplying and dividing the function in order to simplify the function and looking for the "logic" of this problem and yet I still don't know how to solve the problem. Sorry if you guys feel that way! I'll try to solve it again, I'm so sorry :)

Comment: The f in question (b) is not supposed to be the same as the f in question (a), don't get confused by that @user609438.

Comment: The statement in the title is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part **a** let us go to the limit definition of a derivative. That is, the derivative of a function at point a is:

$$\frac{df}{dx_a}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

Consequently, the function becomes:

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{0+h(0+h−1)(0+h−2)\cdots(0+h−n)}{(0+h + 1)(0 +h+ 2)\cdots(0+h + n)}-\frac{0(0−1)(0−2)\cdots(0−n)}{(0 + 1)(0 + 2)\cdots(0 + n)}}{h}$$

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{h(h−1)(h−2)\cdots(h−n)}{(h + 1)(h+ 2)\cdots(h + n)}-\frac{0}{(1)( 2)\cdots( n)}}{h}$$

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{h(h−1)(h−2)\cdots(h−n)}{(h + 1)(h+ 2)\cdots(h + n)}-0}{h}$$

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{h(h−1)(h−2)\cdots(h−n)}{(h + 1)(h+ 2)\cdots(h + n)}}{h}$$

After simplifying the rational we get:

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{h(h−1)(h−2)\cdots(h−n)}{h(h + 1)(h+ 2)\cdots(h + n)}$$

Cancelling out $h$, we get:

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{(h−1)(h−2)\cdots(h−n)}{(h + 1)(h+ 2)\cdots(h + n)}$$

After letting the limit go to zero:

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{(h−1)(h−2)\cdots(h−n)}{(h + 1)(h+ 2)\cdots(h + n)}=\frac{(-1)(-2)\cdots (-n)}{(1)(2)\cdots (n)}=-1$$

Therefore, the derivative at $0$ is -1.

Part **b** is very similar to part one, you just have to use the limit definition of derivative, and then plug-in the disjunctive values given.